# Sending HTTP response to multiple clients

Tags: node.js, http, httpresponse

I need to send a response to 2 clients, even though only one of them can make the request. How  to do that?

Comment: You can't, how would you know where to send it ?

Comment: I need to send a countdown to 2 clients. The first client is waiting for another so that they can play a game. When the second client joins the game, I need to send a countdown to both players.

Comment: You can't send a response if there wasn't a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use socket.io 
http://socket.io/

First the clients open a connection to the server. Then the clients listen to a "event" that the server sends.

Comment: That would be a solution if I could change the client' source code.